# Colouring a Cylinder in MATLAB using the density of points located on it

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I have a plot in MATLAB that is currently just a cylinder. I also have a large set of data points from an experiment that lie on this cylinder. I want to colour the cylinder based on the density of these points (ie. Dark red for high density, fading to blue for low density). I am unsure what the best way to do this would be. Currently I draw the points and the mesh for the cylinder separately. The points are not uniformly spaced.

```
rad = linspace( 0, 1, 100 )  ; 
theta = linspace( 0, 2 * pi, 100 ) ; 

[r, th] = meshgrid( rad, theta ) ; 

x = 190 * cos( th ) ; 
y = 115 * sin( th ) ;  

z = 1730 * r ; 

mesh( x, y, z ) 
hold on

x = [35.12 -44.44 24.98 -17.05 152.52 109.28 -181.85 -72.26 84.45 -89.96 55.02 70.88 172.08 -144.16 44.24 28.81 -30.14 72.79 -126.75 -37.22]

y = [-113.01 -111.80 -114.00 -114.53 -68.57 -94.07 -33.31 -106.35 -103.01 -101.28 -110.07 -106.69 -48.74 -74.90 -111.83 -113.66 -113.54 -106.22 -85.66 -112.71]

z = [1650.59 767.18 845.06 311.28 1352.75 921.70 1111.35 1572.80 1231.16 89.67 891.30 551.67 547.92 983.57 1746.61 1346.11 810.22 465.33 1564.76 1624.73]

scatter3( x, y, z )
```

Below is a pictorial example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: It is an interesting question, but as it is, it's way to broad. Please add some significant code and example data.

Comment: consider using n-dimensional histogram : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23897-n-dimensional-histogram

Comment: @natan, if the points are lying on a cylinder surface, a two-dimensional histogram (`hist3`) applied to cylindric coordinates should be enough.

Comment: @Tyler, can you provide your dataset? The dataset in the question is not large (enough for a density estimation), and the points do not appear to lie on a cylinder surface...

Comment: @A.Donda, I can't provide the entire data set. The points that I did provide do lie on the surface of the cylinder that is drawn though. It does not have an equal x and y axis, so I don't think that I can use the cylinder object that matlab provides.

Comment: @Tyler, ok. Shai's answer is how I would have done it, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky here...

Let's start by estimating the density of the points on the surface of the cylinder, converting their 3D coordinates to 2D (because they are on a 2D surface in 3D space)

```
xx = [35.12 -44.44 24.98 -17.05 152.52 109.28 -181.85 -72.26 84.45 -89.96 55.02 70.88 172.08 -144.16 44.24 28.81 -30.14 72.79 -126.75 -37.22];
yy = [-113.01 -111.80 -114.00 -114.53 -68.57 -94.07 -33.31 -106.35 -103.01 -101.28 -110.07 -106.69 -48.74 -74.90 -111.83 -113.66 -113.54 -106.22 -85.66 -112.71];
zz = [1650.59 767.18 845.06 311.28 1352.75 921.70 1111.35 1572.80 1231.16 89.67 891.30 551.67 547.92 983.57 1746.61 1346.11 810.22 465.33 1564.76 1624.73];

tt = atan2( yy./115, xx./190 ); %// angle in range [-pi pi]
tt( tt<0 ) = tt( tt<0 ) + 2*pi; %// in range [0..2*pi] for compatibility with definition of `theta`.
%//compute density using hist3
[n c] = hist3( [tt;zz]' ); %'// you can play with the granularity here...
```

Extrapolate the histogram over the entire plotting surface

```
d = interpn( c{1}, c{2}, n, th, z, 'linear', 0 );
```

Now we can use the density to color the cylinder

```
mesh( x, y, z, d );
```

Resulting with
[image]

Comment: Exactly the right approach imho – except, instead of extrapolation I would have specified bin edges in the call to `hist3`, such that they cover the whole interval [0, 2pi].

Comment: @A.Donda thank you. As I commented in my code, `hist3` is the place to tweak the the granularity and accuracy of the representation. I only suggested an outline here... But you are right that extrapolation is something that needs attention and careful planing.